# Length-prefix framing with Netty - can't setup LengthFieldPrepender/Decoder

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, udp, netty

In my simple udp netty application, I'm trying to enable Length-prefix framing with netty. I'm using one channel for both handling incoming messages and issuing new messages (#send).

```
public class Server {

    private static final int FRAME_LENGTH_PREFIX_LENGTH = 2;
    private static final int FRAME_MAX_LENGTH = 64 * 1024;

    private static final LengthFieldPrepender frameLengthPrefixPrepender =
        new LengthFieldPrepender(FRAME_LENGTH_PREFIX_LENGTH, true);
    private static final LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder frameLengthPrefixDecoder =
        new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(FRAME_MAX_LENGTH, 0, FRAME_LENGTH_PREFIX_LENGTH,
            -FRAME_LENGTH_PREFIX_LENGTH, FRAME_LENGTH_PREFIX_LENGTH, true);

    private final InetSocketAddress me;

    private final Channel serverChannel;

    private Server(ServerBuilder builder) {
        this.serverChannel = buildServerChannel(builder.inetAddress, builder.port, builder.channel,
            builder.eventLoopExecutors, builder.channelOptions, builder.loggerLevel);

        this.me = new InetSocketAddress(builder.inetAddress, builder.port);
    }

    private Channel buildServerChannel(InetAddress inetAddress, Integer port,
                                       Class<? extends Channel> channel, EventLoopGroup eventExecutors,
                                       Map<ChannelOption, Object> opts, LogLevel logLevel) {

        val b = new Bootstrap();

        b.group(eventExecutors)
            .channel(channel);
        opts.forEach(b::option);

        b.handler(new ChannelInitializer<DatagramChannel>() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(DatagramChannel ch) throws Exception {
                val pipe = ch.pipeline();

                if (logLevel != null)
                    pipe.addLast(new LoggingHandler(logLevel));

                // pipe.addLast(frameLengthPrefixDecoder); // disabled for testing purposes

                pipe.addLast(new SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket msg) throws Exception {
                        ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg.copy().content();
                        byte[] req = new byte[buf.readableBytes()];
                        buf.readBytes(req);
                        String body = new String(req, CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
                        System.out.println("SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket> : "+body);
                    }
                });

                pipe.addLast(frameLengthPrefixPrepender);
            }
        });
        return b.bind(inetAddress, port).syncUninterruptibly().channel();
    }

    private ChannelFuture send(InetSocketAddress dest, ByteBuf data) {
        val datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, dest, me);

        return serverChannel.writeAndFlush(datagramPacket);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to send a "Hello" message:

```
public static void main(String[] a) throws UnknownHostException {
    Server build = new Server().loggerLevel(LogLevel.DEBUG).build();
    build.send(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 1080), Unpooled.copiedBuffer("HELLO".getBytes()));
}
```

And what I would expect is:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 00 07 48 45 4c 4c 4f                            |..HELLO         |
           ^^^^^ prefix
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Nevertheless, it's still:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 48 45 4c 4c 4f                                  |HELLO           |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

I also tried to debug `LengthFieldPrepender/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` by placing breakpoints `LengthFieldPrepender#encode and LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder#decode` and found out these methods not being called at all.

I made a couple of hello world netty tcp application this exact way and never had problems. I feel there is a very simple explanation what I did wrong, but I'm struggling to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you are directly writing a DatagramPacket to the channel's pipeline and the outbound handler LengthFieldPrepender only accepts objects of type ByteBuf. Hence, the datagram skips the encoder.